# Нарисовать ER-диаграмму из словаря

Tags: python, er-diagram

У меня есть словарь формата:

```
{view_name1:[tab1, tab2, view_name2], view_name2:[tab4, tab99, view_name43].....}
```

Надо нарисовать ER-диаграмму из него. Знаю про eralchemy и sqlalchemy_schema_display, но там можно это делать только из моделей или самих бд.

То есть, есть ли возможность сделать это из словаря или надо как-то преобразовать в модель, если это вообще как-то возможно?

Comment: Есть модуль `diagrams`, который позволяет рисовать диаграммы на основе простых данных. Но я не уверен, можно ли там отрисовывать линки по Чену.